# pass where clause as parameter to another function laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method which handles the query processing from the data table.

Right now the function looks like this:

```
   $rowsPerPage = $request->get('rowsPerPage') ? $request->get('rowsPerPage') : 10;
    $sortBy = $request->get('sortBy');
    $desc = $request->get('descending');
    $query = $request->get('query');

    $modelData = Airline::where('id', '>', 0);
    if ($query) {
        $modelData = $modelData->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('airline_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->where('iata_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        })->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($query){
            $q->where('country_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        });
    }


    if ($sortBy == 'null') {
        $sortBy = 'created_at';
        $desc = false;
    }
    if ($desc) {
        $modelData->orderBy($sortBy, 'DESC');
    } else {
        $modelData->orderBy($sortBy, 'ASC');
    }
    $rowsPerPage = $rowsPerPage==-1 ? $modelData->count() : $rowsPerPage;

    $modelData = $modelData->paginate($rowsPerPage);

    return  $modelData;
```

This is working fine but I am repairing the same code again in another controller method. The only thing that changes between the controller is the `whereClause` method. I want to put all the code in this method to another function except for this part.

```
 $modelData->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('airline_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->where('iata_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($query){
        $q->where('country_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    });
```

I want to pass this where clause as a parameter to a new function, for example:

```
public static function IndexQuery($model,$whereClause){

    $rowsPerPage = request('rowsPerPage')? request('rowsPerPage') : 10;
    $sortBy = request('sortBy');
    $desc = request('descending');
    //Where clause pass should execute here with model object .
   if ($sortBy == 'null') {
        $sortBy = 'created_at';
        $desc = false;
    }
    if ($desc) {
        $model->orderBy($sortBy, 'DESC');
    } else {
        $model->orderBy($sortBy, 'ASC');
    }
    $rowsPerPage = $rowsPerPage==-1 ? $model->count() : $rowsPerPage;

    $data = $model->paginate($rowsPerPage);
    return $data;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
public function WhereClause($q,$query)
{
 $qdata= $modelData->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('airline_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->where('iata_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($query){
        $q->where('country_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    });
  return $qdata;
}
```

//controller

```
$qresult=$this->WhereClause($data1, $data2);
public static function IndexQuery($model,$qresult){

    $rowsPerPage = request('rowsPerPage')? request('rowsPerPage') : 10;
    $sortBy = request('sortBy');
    $desc = request('descending');
    //Where clause pass should execute here with model object .
   if ($sortBy == 'null') {
        $sortBy = 'created_at';
        $desc = false;
    }
    if ($desc) {
        $model->orderBy($sortBy, 'DESC');
    } else {
        $model->orderBy($sortBy, 'ASC');
    }
    $rowsPerPage = $rowsPerPage==-1 ? $model->count() : $rowsPerPage;

    $data = $model->paginate($rowsPerPage);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: That can also  be a option but it would be better if I can pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Laravel Model Scope** for this. Try using Model Local Scope like:

**// inside you model Airline.php**

```
public function scopeFilterWithQuery($queryBuilder, $query)
{
    if($query) {

        $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('airline_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->where('iata_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        })->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($query){
            $q->where('country_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        });
    }

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

**// Now in controller**

```
$modelData = Airline::where('id', '>', 0)->filterWithQuery($query);

// your other codes.
```

You can wrap as much as common conditions in model scope and reuse that.

Comment: Here is the documentation link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: You just approved [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23259610) which translated a post. As per [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/) please reject those edits. Reasons for this are that you can't be sure to translate all their intentions correctly, and, more importantly, we cannot be sure whether the OP speaks any English, and thus whether they will be able to communicate with us on clarifications and answers.